# Is it possible to concatenate 'case when' results into one column?

Tags: sql-server

In the following SQL, I am having issues concatenating the case when results into one column. I would like the B.DAYNUM field to display the results in the following way: Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed, etc. The days scheduled will vary per week. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT A.SHORTNM AS 'SCHEDULE GROUP'
,RTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.STARTDTM,110),10)) AS STARTDATE
,A.SHORTNM AS 'PATTERN TEMPLATE' 
,A.LONGDSC AS 'PATTERN DESCRIPTION'
,A.DAYCNT AS 'DAYS IN PATTERN'
,C.LABELNM AS 'SHIFT'
,LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),E.STARTDTM,100),7)) AS SHIFTSTART
,LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),G.STARTDTM,100),7)) AS BREAKSTART
,LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),H.ENDDTM,100),7)) AS BREAKEND
,CASE WHEN F1.ORDERNUM = 3 THEN 
    LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),F1.ENDDTM,100),7)) 
    ELSE LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),F.ENDDTM,100),7)) END AS SHIFTEND1
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 1 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 2 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 3 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 4 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 5 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 6 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 7 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS 'SCHED DAYS-WK 1'
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 8 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 9 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 10 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 11 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 12 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 13 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 14 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS 'SCHED DAYS-WK 2'
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 15 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 16 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 17 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 18 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 19 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 20 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 21 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 3"
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 22 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 23 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 24 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 25 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 26 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 27 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 28 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 4"
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 29 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 30 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 31 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 32 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 33 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 34 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 35 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 5"
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 36 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 37 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 38 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 39 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 40 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 41 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 42 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 6"
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 43 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 44 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 45 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 46 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 47 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 48 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 49 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 7"
,CASE WHEN B.DAYNUM = 50 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 51 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 52 THEN 'TUES'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 53 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 54 THEN 'THURS'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 55 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN B.DAYNUM = 56 THEN 'SAT'
    ELSE '' END AS "Sched Days-Week 8"
FROM SCHEDULEPATTRN A 
JOIN SCHEDPATTRNDAY B ON A.SCHEDULEPATTRNID = B.SCHEDULEPATTRNID
JOIN SHIFTCODE C ON B.SHIFTCODEID = C.SHIFTCODEID
LEFT JOIN SHIFTSEGMENT E ON C.SHIFTCODEID = E.SHIFTCODEID AND E.ORDERNUM = 1
LEFT JOIN SHIFTSEGMENT F ON C.SHIFTCODEID = F.SHIFTCODEID AND F.SHIFTSEGMNTTYPID = 1 AND F.ORDERNUM = 1
LEFT JOIN SHIFTSEGMENT F1 ON C.SHIFTCODEID = F1.SHIFTCODEID AND F1.SHIFTSEGMNTTYPID = 1 AND F1.ORDERNUM = 3
LEFT JOIN SHIFTSEGMENT G ON C.SHIFTCODEID = G.SHIFTCODEID AND G.SHIFTSEGMNTTYPID = 4 AND G.ORDERNUM = 2
LEFT JOIN SHIFTSEGMENT H ON C.SHIFTCODEID = H.SHIFTCODEID AND H.SHIFTSEGMNTTYPID = 4 AND H.ORDERNUM = 2
JOIN TIMEPERIODTYPE I ON A.TIMEPERIODTYPEID = I.TIMEPERIODTYPEID
AND A.TEMPLATESW = 1
AND A.SHORTNM NOT LIKE 'z%'
ORDER BY A.SHORTNM,B.DAYNUM
```

Comment: What dbms are you using? Always include dbms type and version, use tags for this. Each dbms has different ways of solving your question. That is why we need to know.

Comment: Why not use built in functions like Day() and Week() and datepart() on your date column?

Comment: You could always do something weird like an outer apply, e.g. add this to your statement... `OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(dayName, '') dayName FROM (VALUES (0, 'SAT'), (1, 'SUN'), (2, 'MON'), (3, 'TUES'), (4, 'WED'), (5, 'THURS'), (6, 'FRI'))T(dayNum, dayName) WHERE B.DAYNUM % 7 = T.dayNum) T` then just select T.dayName in your query.

Comment: Sorry about that. We are on SQL Server 2008.